# linq query works on every machine but mine

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

So, I have a simple linq query.  Other programmers (all on Win7, VS2010) can run the select without issue.  I can use SQL Profiler on my machine to hit the server db (we are all hitting the same SQL Server 2008 db on a development server) and see the actual query works in SQL Server Mgmt studio from my machine, but the IQueryable object returns 0 results.

We are all using the same exact code base (everything is checked into Hg and we are all synched).  I have restarted my machine and the server the db resides on in case there was some caching going on.

If I remove the where clause I actually get results back.  We are all at a loss.  Anyone have any bright ideas???

Here is the code in case you want to see but I don't think it matters in this case:

```
IQueryable<MOffice> offices = (from returnData in entityModel.MOffices
                                             where returnData.HiringProjectCoordinator == true
                                             select returnData).Take((int)topCount);
            return offices.ToList();
```

Comment: Well, it is obvious something different between your machines or the statement that "the code and DB is exactly the same". Is not true.  Either way there is almost no way we can psychically debug this for you.  One question though; what is the value of `topCount`, where does it come from, and what happens if you remove the `Take(topCount)` call comepletely?

Comment: Are you absolutely, totally, completely 100% sure you're hitting the same database as the other machines?

Comment: Code and db are exactly the same. 3 guys confirmed it for me. See the solution - its fixed now but definitely the weirdest thing I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var results = entityModel.MOffices
                  .Where(x=>x.HiringProjectCoordinator == true)
                  .OrderBy(x=>x.Something)
                //.Take(int.Parse(topCount))
                  .ToList();
int count = results.Count();
return results;
```

Inspect that count is as you expect. Remove the comment as needed.

- Does the query work on [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?
- Confirmed everyone is referencing the same database? For sure? i.e. change one particular record firstName to 'foo' to determine.
- Does a similar query to another table act same?

Comment: I tried that as well and it doesn't work (again, works on all other developer machines)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant change the style of the query.  If I do not select a topcount (take) like you suggested then it works?!?!  Of course, I need to limit it to 10 or 20, so what would you suggest?

Comment: HAHA. I am stumped.  After removing Take() and putting it back in (same exact code) it works on my machine (or maybe it was that third restart).  Thx for the help

Comment: This sounds like you had a dll that was not compiling and contained an older version of the code.  That being said I have a BA in our group the every once in a while throws errors when executing a certain feature (which is linq heavy).  We were never able to explain why it was doing that.  My guess is you may have some type of corruption in your .net stack.

Answer (score -1):

Use LinqPad then inspect the generated SQL statement of your LINQ.

Comment: If you read my question you will see I used profiler to inspect the actual SQL and found it executed propertly and returned the correct number of results